# Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001B6E7CC5930>,

Tags: python, python-3.x, traceback

i tried to make a web site traffic increaser but i got an error like "Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001B6E7CC5930>,"
So how will i fix that? i have a problem about proxys timeout.

and thats the Traceback over here :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emreb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Web Traffic\proxychecker.py", line 182, in <module>
    sending()
  File "C:\Users\emreb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Web Traffic\proxychecker.py", line 176, in sending
    requests.get(url, proxies=proxies2, verify=False, timeout=5)
  File "C:\Users\emreb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emreb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emreb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emreb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emreb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 504, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='grabify.link', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /4VFAZU (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001B6E7CC5930>, 'Connection to 91.230.199.174 timed out. (connect timeout=5)'))
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can fix this problem by setting timeout parameter. like this

```
session.get(url, headers=header, proxy=myproxy,timeout=30)
```